# Django: How to automatically reset a boolean field to it's default after some time (eg. 6 months) to make full access for a page expire

Tags: django

I am fairly new to django and I have the problem of creating full access for a site. The user has to give some additional information to get full access after signing up. I want the full access to automatically expire after 6 months. I defined a custom user model with the extra condition:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    full_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    has_full_access = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #some other stuff
```

After typing in some data for getting full access, the user gets redirected to this view which sets the boolean to true:

views.py

```
def data_gathered_done(request):
    current_user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    current_user.has_full_access = True
    current_user.save()
    #some other stuff
```

I want this boolean field to automatically reset to it's default (False) 6 months after the full access has been granted. How can I do that?

Comment: add datetime field `valid_until` and set it's value when you activate the user. Run a cronjob each night where you loop over active users and deactivate all with `valid_until < now()`. If you cannot run cron, you will have to verify this every time they log in. Do it in login view

Comment: Thanks for the immediate comment and answer, I had to adjust a little bit, but it works now!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with a property on the Model.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

expire_after = timedelta(days=180)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    full_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    full_access_since = models.DatetimeField(auto_add_now=True)
    #some other stuff

    @property
    def has_full_access(self):
        return datetime.now() - expire_after < self.full_access_since
```

Then you can use the Boolean normally

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

user = CostumUser.objects.get(pk=123)
if not user.has_full_access:
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to this question, but I had a somewhat similar problem recently where I needed a boolean "lock" that "expired" after a 90 minutes.  I didn't want to install any third-party dependencies or packages to do this.

**The scenario:** When a user accesses an "edit mode" view/template from a given model instance's detail view, I need to lock out all other users to prevent concurrency issues. 
However after X minutes, I want others to be able to edit so I needed the UI menu options to revert back.

(**Note:** In my case I have to deal with concurrency at the database level as well, but this solution deals with the UI.)  However, the logic could be extended to handle other time-based access issues within a site or webapp.

If I handled this only client side (say with AJAX), a user might lock a model and potentially their computer blows up, hence no AJAX fires to unlock.  Has to be back-end.  Like the answer above, a function that checks timestamps on the model seems like the way to go, but then again I have users all over the world - how do I deal with daylight savings and different timezones?

My solution was to use a non-DST timezone as a time constant so I didn't have to worry about that.  Who cares what timezone I'm benchmarking - it's just a back-end method that checks durations.

**models.py**

```
class SomeProduct(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField()
    description = models.TextField()
    lock        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

**views.py**

```
import datetime
import pytz

def update_product_view(request, slug): # This view shows forms and locks out other editors

    qs = SomeProduct.objects.get(slug=slug):

    if qs.lock == False:
        qs.lock = True
        now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Hawaii')) #Hawaii time is constant, no DST
        qs.timestamp = now
        qs.save()
    elif qs.lock == True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Hawaii')) 
        qs.timestamp = now
        qs.save()
    else:
        pass

    # Forms and other view logic here...



def product_view(request, slug): # This view unlocks the model if enough time has passed

    qs = SomeProduct.objects.get(slug=slug):

    if qs is not None:
        try: # in case no timestamp has been set
            now     = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Hawaii')) 
            then    = qs.timestamp
            delta = (now-then).total_seconds() # compare the difference 
            minutes = 60 #seconds
            if delta > 90*minutes:
                qs.lock = False # if 90 or more minutes have passed, unlock the model
                qs.save()
            else:
                pass
        except:
            pass
    else:
        pass

    # context and other view logic here...
```

**template**

```
{% if obj.lock == True %}
# adjust edit options or hide buttons accordingly
{% else obj.lock == False %}
# show button that leads to edit view url
{% endif %}
```

This is a pretty simplified version of my code, but the basics are there.  I also have some JS on the front end that informs the user with a timeclock, exit edit mode URL that unlocks the model, etc.  Your needs may vary.  If anybody has some perspective on how I can make this better or any "gotchas" I'd love to learn something so please share.  For now this works!